# Are enum names interned in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Are enum names interned in Java?

I.e. is it guaranteed that `enum1.name() == enum2.name()` in case of the same name? And is it safe to compare `enum.name()` to a String that is guaranteed to be interned.

Comment: If the Javadoc doesn't tell you it is, then no. That is, if you're hoping to take two members of two different enums that have the same name and compare their names, you had better use the `equals` method.

Comment: Given I just ran [this ideone program](http://ideone.com/cE8OgD) and it output true, I'd say that there's some evidence to suggest they may be, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @PM77-1 sure, `name()`

Comment: @DanTemple but unless this is documented somewhere, then in other Java implementations or versions it may not be true.

Comment: @fge I think OP means if you have two `enum` types, with both having a constant with the same name as the other.

Comment: I understand the question if its based on morbid curiosity, but when this would actually matter or be useful escapes me

Comment: @AmirAfghani I'm comparing enum name to a String that I know is interned, a valid case isn't it

Comment: How is this not duplicate more 6 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Comment: @OlegMikheev: In general, it's a good practice to assume that interning is done or not done by an evil demon out to get you, to never depend on interning, and only use `.equals` to compare strings.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Although there is no explicit guarantee of this, the end result is bound to be such that the comparison always succeeds for `enum` constants with identical names:

```
enum A {enum1};
enum B {enum1};
System.out.println(A.enum1.name() == B.enum1.name()); // Prints "true"
```

The reason for this is that Java compiler constructs subclasses of `Enum` in such a way that they end up calling `Enum`'s sole protected constructor, passing it the name of `enum` value:

```
protected Enum(String name, int ordinal);
```

The name is embedded into the generated code in the form of a string literal. According to `String` documentation,

> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.

This amounts to an implicit guarantee of your expression succeeding when names of `enum` constants are identical. However, I would not rely on this behavior, and use `equals(...)` instead, because anyone reading my code would be scratching his head, thinking that I made a mistake.

Comment: If you would have written it I would have scratched my head in disbelief :) I would consider it a mistake, and I'm in no doubt that static code analyzers would flag this down as such (found it: it's called "StringLiteralEquality" in CheckStyle, for instance).

Comment: OK, that was one for literals, [this one here](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#ES_COMPARING_STRINGS_WITH_EQ) is the object based one in findbugs (that scans byte code).

Comment: If two string literals or enums contain the same characters but appear in different packages, is there any guarantee that they will identify the same string instance after the packages are loaded?

Comment: @supercat all string literals get passed to [`String.intern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) method, ensuring that string literals from all packages produce the same object for identical strings.

Comment: "However, I would not rely on this behavior […] because anyone reading my code would be scratching his head, thinking that I made a mistake." <— This sounds like the sort of colleague I want to be working with and/or inheriting code from

Answer (score 34):

### No.

[Dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27908402/1273080) is the best answer we have so far. There he says:

> The reason for this is that Java compiler constructs subclasses of
>   `Enum` in such a way that they end up calling `Enum's` sole protected
>   constructor, passing it the name of `enum` value

and there they get interned, because they're string constants.

But, in [the JLS, 8.9.2, Enum Body Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2), there's this:

> In practice, a compiler is likely to mirror the `Enum` type by
>   declaring `String` and `int` parameters in the default constructor of
>   an `enum` type. However, these parameters are not specified as
>   "implicitly declared" because **different compilers do not need to
>   agree on the form of the default constructor**. Only the compiler of
>   an `enum` type knows how to instantiate the `enum` constants; other
>   compilers can simply rely on the implicitly declared `public static`
>   fields of the `enum` type
>   ([§8.9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3))
>   without regard for how those fields were initialized.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So we'll call the constructor, but we aren't forced to do it in any particular way, and we can manage our own constructor in the compiler.

Therefore, it's completely possible for me to write a correct and JLS-compliant Java compiler that would not intern the names somehow, probably by not having the names stored as a literals. Yes, it would do it on purpose to maliciously break your code, but it would be correct behaviour per spec.

---

### Practically said, Yes.

Every sane implementation will intern the strings. I'd say it's safe to *assume* this kind of behaviour. It's not guaranteed, though, and therefore if I saw this in real code, I'd be very unsatisfied with it even if it was thoroughly described in a comment.

Please, don't rely on such unspecified and implementation-specific behaviour. If you really, really have to, write a unit test for it. And put an `assert` in the code, and lots of explaining. Measure whether your approach will actually do anything.

<s>Consider looping over the `enum` members' names and `intern()` them manually before using them. That way, it will be immediatelly clear what you're doing.</s> This doesn't work reliably. See comments.

Comment: "Consider looping over the enum members' names and `intern()` them manually" I don't think this would work. `intern()` returns the canonical string which will not be the same instance you passed in if a different instance was interned before.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ohhh. It might actually not work if something else interned a string equal to a enum member's name, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

With strings you're going to want to use the equals method of Strings. That aside, you already have the enum that you could compare with the equality operator. Under what scenario would this arise?

That being said, yes, the .equals method will return true if they are the same.

I'm not sure about equality operator, and without looking it up, I can tell you that it's poor programming to use it if it is.

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb that if it does not explicitly say it in the api, assume that it could change from version to version. This helps in preventing brittle code.

Answer (score -1):

The Oracle documentation about Enum says (first line):

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants. *The variable must be equal to one of the values that have been predefined* for it. Common examples include compass directions (values of NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, and WEST) and the days of the week.

If this is true then, yes, your `enum1.name() == enum2.name()` is guaranteed to be true if the names are the same.

Also, in the method `name()` javadoc:

> public final String name() 
>    
>   Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration. Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name. This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which *will not vary* from release to release.
>    
>    
>      Returns: the name of this enum constant

For example, if you had two enums, `Days` and `MyDays`, where SUNDAY is a common value, == between the enum object values, SUNDAY will return true as you are comparing two strings - see the working example in http://ideone.com/U1Bmcw.

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static enum Day{SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY};
    public static enum MyDays{SUNDAY};

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        MyDays m = Ideone.MyDays.SUNDAY;
        Day d = Ideone.Day.SUNDAY;

        System.out.println(d.name() == m.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: Only if OP meant two members of the same enum.

Comment: And of course I didn't mean the same enum :) I'm comparing enum names to `String`s that are guaranteed to be interned

Comment: Again, how can you say this is guaranteed? The fact that you tested this on a particular version and implementation of Java does not mean it's guaranteed. Is there any documentation or requirement of the Java language that guarantees this?