# Why does using == with Enum.toString() work?

Tags: java, enums, equality

```
public enum Style {
    BIG,MEDIUM,SMALL;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Style.SMALL.toString() == "SMALL");
    }
  
}
```

Why does this work? I expect the print to be false, since `==` compares the object references. However, it prints `true`.

I would appreciate if someone can explain the underlying behaviour.

Comment: I don't think this behaviour is actually specified. The docs for [`Enum.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) doesn't say that the returned string will be an interned one, so depending on the implementation, I think this could give you `false`.

Comment: Interesting, this has been like this for years on a project im working on, and its been running bug free.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27908213/5754656  (Since `Enum#toString()` just calls `Enum#name()`)

Comment: but remember that small strings are heaped, so it would still end up being true on any proper jvm

Comment: The real answer is:  It’s not surprising that this works, but you cannot safely assume it will always work.